# SQL average value for multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a table which can be simplefied to to following columns:

```
[A] | [B] | [C] | [D] | [Value]
```

With my basic query I get 3 or 4 rows (it varies) where **A**, **B**, **C** and **D** is identical, but with different values. Now I want to combine these 3 (or 4) rows into one row, with the average value instead of the individual value. Is there a simple way to do this, using the SQL average function?

The code looks like this (renamed variables to to company politics):

```
DECLARE @startTime datetime;
DECLARE @endTime datetime;

SET @startTime = '2015-01-26 00:00:00:000';
SET @endTime   = '2015-02-26 00:00:00:000';

SELECT 
table1.A,
table1.B,
table1.C,
table1.D,
table4.E,
table4.F,
table4.VALUE,
table4.G

FROM 
table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.C = table1.C
INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.X = table2.X
INNER JOIN table4 ON table4.Y = table3.Y

WHERE
table1.A > @startTime
AND table1.A < @endTime
AND table4.E = 'something'

ORDER BY table1.A asc;
```

Comment: You have answered your own question by mentioning the Average function. Whatever RDBMS system you are using will have ample documentation online which will describe how to use it.

Comment: @Tobsey you mean like [these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)? That's the first hit for a quick search of "sql server average examples". With five examples, three of them relevant to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use

```
SELECT 
       table1.A,
       table1.B,
       table1.C,
       table1.D,
       avg(table4.value) value,
       avg(table4.e)     e,
       avg(table4.f)     f,
       avg(table4.g)     g
  from ...
 group by table1.A,
          table1.B,
          table1.C,
          table1.D
```

If you need the avg value of multiple columns (f.e. table4.value, table4.e, table4.f, table4.g) as one result column you should have a look onto the `UNPIVOT` function (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/125504/)

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to do the job. Still not quite sure how it differs from some of the things I've tried, but thats a minor issue. Again, thanks for the quick response :-).